# How to select an item from a JList without using a button?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I've been making a program, and one part of it is the ability to choose an item from a `JList` and have it display a specific icon in a `JLabel`. I've made it work so that the user has to select the item from the list and then press a button to initiate the action.

I'm just wondering if there's any way to make it so the button isn't necessary? In other words, the user simply has to click the list item and it immediately initiates the action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class Example extends JFrame 
{
  JList list = null;

  Example() 
  {
    Container cp = getContentPane();

    cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

    data.add("Py");
    data.add("Piper");

    list = new JList(data.toArray());

    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() 
    {

      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) 
      {
        // To avoid double value selected
        if (evt.getValueIsAdjusting())
                  return;
        System.out.println("Selected: " + list.getSelectedValue());
      }

    });

    cp.add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

  public static void main(String[] s)
  {
    Example l = new Example();
    l.pack();
    l.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

So right here:

```
list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() 
{

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) 
    {
         // To avoid double value selected
         if (evt.getValueIsAdjusting())
            return;
         System.out.println("Selected: " + list.getSelectedValue());
    }

});
```

So what you are actually doing is to "plug" a ListSelectionListener to your JList so that can be notified for any events that occur to the JList.  Within the `valueChanged` you add the code need to be executed when the user select something in the JList.

Comment: You would use the term ActionListener when adding an ActionListener object, again something that your code does not do. You should say that you're adding a ListSelectionListener to the JList, so that the program will be notified of any changes in the selection's state.

Comment: People tend to copy Stack Overflow answers verbatim.  I would feel better about this answer if this code didn't ignore generics, made proper use of the AWT event dispatch thread, and didn't use a BorderLayout constraint with a FlowLayout.

Answer (score 0):

There is this wonderful resource with the [JList JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#addListSelectionListener(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener)).